# fulfilling quantity required using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working with mysql and php and I need to work out how to fulfil a quantity for a particular request:
if this is my request table:

`request id[pk], custID[fk from customer table], productid[fk in products table], quantites_requested, price_requested`
this is the advertised_products table:

`advertiseid[pk], customerid[fk from customer table], productsid[fk in products table], quantites_advertised, price_advertised`

if I have this record in my request table:

```
1,1,1,10.0,5.00
```

and the following as advertised quantities:

```
1,2,1,4.00,2.00 -- This means customer id 2 is selling choclates(product id 1), for 4KG's @£2.00
2,3,1,5.00,2.50
3,4,1,1.00,1.00
4,5,1,10.00,6.00
```

How would I be able to use an sql select statement so that: I can make up the customer's request quantity?

I wanted to be able to select the cheapest total that makes up the requested quantity.

so, in this case the output would show:

```
2,1,4.00,2.00
3,1,5.00,2.50
4,1,1.00,1.00
```

so customer 2,3 and 4 would be displayed as their quantities of 4+5+1=10.0 makes up the requested quantity... and it is also cheaper then seller number 5.

Is there any such query I can use so that I would be able to look up the SQL table and cumulatively add up the quantities until the requested amount and then check which is the cheapest one to use?

Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451965/optimal-selection-for-ordering-multiple-items-parts-from-multiple-suppliers-v).

As pointed out in the answer by @Origin this is a [set coverage problem](http://math.mit.edu/~goemans/18434S06/setcover-tamara.pdf) and  is an [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete) problem i.e. uncomputable for any but a very small number of possibilities.

For your problem a greedy algorithm solution may be adequate.

I don't have time to solve your problem but posted below is the code that I used to solve mine. Your table structure is simpler so your solution should be too!

```
DECLARE @GreedySetCover table
(
    Location_Id int
    ,Supplier_Id int
    ,Ranking int
)

INSERT INTO @GreedySetCover
--Include Suppliers who are sole suppliers for any item
SELECT  ss.Location_Id
        ,si.Supplier_Id
        ,0 Ranking
FROM    (
        SELECT  pr.Location_Id
                ,pr.Item_Id
        FROM    PartsRequests pr
                INNER JOIN
                SupplierItems si ON pr.Item_Id=si.Item_Id
        WHERE   pr.Order_Id IS NULL
        GROUP BY    pr.Location_Id
                    ,pr.Item_Id
        HAVING  COUNT(*)=1
        ) ss
        INNER JOIN
        SupplierItems si ON si.Item_Id=ss.Item_Id
UNION
--Include suppliers who do not charge a delivery fee
SELECT  pr.Location_Id
        ,si1.Supplier_Id
        ,0 Ranking
FROM    PartsRequests pr
        INNER JOIN
        SupplierItems si1 ON si1.Item_Id=pr.Item_Id
WHERE   pr.Order_Id IS NULL
        AND
        (
        NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT ISNULL(si2.AmountPerOrder,0)
        FROM    SupplierItems si2
        WHERE   si1.Supplier_Id=si2.Supplier_Id
                AND
                si2.Item_Id=0)
        OR
        (SELECT ISNULL(si2.AmountPerOrder,0)
        FROM    SupplierItems si2
        WHERE   si1.Supplier_Id=si2.Supplier_Id
                AND
                si2.Item_Id=0
        )=0
        )


DECLARE @Ranking int = 1
--While any item does not have a supplier
WHILE   EXISTS 
        (
        SELECT  pr.Location_Id
                ,pr.Item_Id
        FROM    PartsRequests pr
                EXCEPT  
                (
                SELECT  gsc.Location_Id
                        ,pr1.Item_Id
                FROM    @GreedySetCover gsc
                        INNER JOIN
                        SupplierItems si ON gsc.Supplier_Id=si.Supplier_Id
                        INNER JOIN
                        PartsRequests pr1 ON pr1.Item_Id=si.Item_Id AND pr1.Location_Id=gsc.Location_Id
                WHERE pr1.ORDER_ID IS NULL
                )
        )
BEGIN
    --Get the supllier whcovere uncovered items at the lowest cost
    INSERT INTO @GreedySetCover
    SELECT  sort.Location_Id
            ,sort.Supplier_Id
            ,@Ranking 
    FROM    (
            SELECT  uncovered.Location_Id
                    ,si.Supplier_Id
                    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                        (PARTITION BY uncovered.Location_Id
                         ORDER BY   
                         --This is the weighting function 
                         SUM(uncovered.Quantity*si.Price) +         --The cost of the Items
                         (SELECT    ISNULL(si2.AmountPerOrder,0)    --Plus the delivery fee
                          FROM      SupplierItems si2
                          WHERE     si.Supplier_Id=si2.Supplier_Id
                                    AND
                                    si2.Item_Id=0)
                         /cast(COUNT(*) as float)) RowNum           --Divided by the number of items covered
            FROM    (
                    SELECT pr.Location_Id
                          ,pr.Item_Id
                          ,pr.Quantity
                    FROM    PartsRequests pr
                            --Remove uncovered items
                            EXCEPT  
                            (
                            SELECT  gsc.Location_Id
                                    ,pr1.Item_Id
                                    ,pr1.Quantity
                            FROM    @GreedySetCover gsc
                                    INNER JOIN
                                    SupplierItems si ON gsc.Supplier_Id=si.Supplier_Id
                                    INNER JOIN
                                    PartsRequests pr1 ON pr1.Item_Id=si.Item_Id AND pr1.Location_Id=gsc.Location_Id
                            WHERE pr1.ORDER_ID IS NULL
                            )
                    ) uncovered
                    INNER JOIN
                    SupplierItems si ON si.Item_Id=uncovered.Item_Id
            GROUP BY Location_Id, Supplier_Id
            ) sort
    WHERE RowNum = 1

    SET @Ranking=@Ranking+1
END

--SELECT    *
--FROM  @GreedySetCover
--ORDER BY  Ranking 
--          ,Location_Id

SELECT  Location_Id
        ,Supplier_Id
        ,Number
        ,Quantity
        ,Price
FROM    (
        SELECT  pr.Id PartsRequest_Id
                ,pr.Item_Id
                ,pr.Quantity
                ,pr.RequestTime
                ,pr.Location_Id
                ,pr.Person_Id
                ,pr.Order_Id
                ,si.Supplier_Id
                ,si.Number
                ,si.Price
                ,si.AmountPerOrder      
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY gsc.Location_Id,pr.Item_Id
                                    ORDER BY si.Price) RowNum
        FROM    @GreedySetCover gsc
                INNER JOIN  
                PartsRequests pr ON gsc.Location_Id=pr.Location_Id
                INNER JOIN
                SupplierItems si ON gsc.Supplier_Id=si.Supplier_Id
                                    AND
                                    pr.Item_Id=si.Item_Id
        ) Results
WHERE   RowNum=1
UNION
SELECT  gsc.Location_Id
        ,si.Supplier_Id
        ,si.Number
        ,si.AmountPerOrder
        ,Price
FROM    @GreedySetCover gsc
        INNER JOIN
        SupplierItems si ON gsc.Supplier_Id=si.Supplier_Id
WHERE   AmountPerOrder>0
ORDER BY    Location_Id
            ,Supplier_Id
            ,Number
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for getting in touch. I read your question and 'Origin' answer. I believe we do have a similar problem indeed. I am using mysql and PHP.
I appreciate you dont have time to solve my problem. However, I would be so greatful if you could take a quick look over here **[link](http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/mysql-help-fulfil-customer-requests-940049.html)** If you look at **post number 5** then You will fully understand what I'm trying to do. Any help provided will be highly valued. If not then its okay I understand you are busy too. Spent hours upon end on this:(

Comment: If you post some sample data at sql www.fiddle.com I will see what I can do

Comment: see the problem is not with the query. As I am matching the requested products to the list of available sellers selling that product. However, my problem is say a customer has requested 10kg of apples. and you have suppliers 1,2,3 selling 1,5,6 kg's for ..£1,£4,£6 respectively I need to find a way so that the 10KG request can be met in the cheapest way possible and then updating the seller table. I believe I would need to use php to do something like this. As I already have the query showing requests and sellers for a particular product. Hence,..

Comment: you may take a look at post number 5 on here http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/mysql-help-fulfil-customer-requests-940049.html 
where you can see what I need to try and do as I have shown the queries and the issue there. Once again thanks very much for your time in helping me.

Comment: You can do it in either. The solution for an approximate optimal (which may be the real optimal) is a greedy algorithm. For a true optimal you need a branch and prune solution.

Comment: Oh okay I see. I shall check up on that in that case. Thanks